# TCP error code 10013 Cross Domain Policy Error with netTcpBinding Service and Silverlight Client

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis, iis-7, nettcpbinding

Was wondeirng if anybody could get me out of my cross domain policy hell.

I have a duplex WCF service which uses `netTcpBining`, and the client is a Silverlight 4 app. When I self host the service, then it works perfectly and my Silverlight clients can consume the service with no problems. However when I host it in IIS 7, that's when the trouble starts. When I host it in IIS I'm able to see the service at:

`http://localhost/Conference/VideoConferenceService.svc`

And when I add a reference to the service which is hosted in IIS, and try to call it, I get a:

> CommunicationException: Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://localhost/Conference/VideoConferenceService.svc. The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:03.3071892. TCP
>   error code 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions.. This could be due to attempting
>   to access a service in a cross-domain way while the service is not
>   configured for cross-domain access. You may need to contact the owner
>   of the service to expose a sockets cross-domain policy over HTTP and
>   host the service in the allowed sockets port range 4502-4534.

Or if seeing the actual error helps inspire those who have seen it before, here is what it throws at me in `Reference.cs`:

[image]

I have checked out almost every solution suggested regarding solving the cross-domain policy error, and I've put my `clientaccesspolicy.xml` in my default website root in IIS, and also in `wwwroot`. I've also turned off all my firewalls. I'm able to see the policy at `http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml`
and also at `http://127.0.0.1/clientaccesspolicy.xml` but I still get this error.

Here is my web.config for the service hosted in IIS 7:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
  </runtime>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>
   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
       <service name="VideoServer.VideoConferenceService">
         <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService" contract="VideoServer.IVideoConferenceService" />
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <host>
           <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:4502/VideoServer/" />
           </baseAddresses>
         </host>
       </service>
     </services>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService" portSharingEnabled="true" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" listenBacklog="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" openTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" sendTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
            <transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And here is the Silverlight client's `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/Conference/VideoConferenceService.svc"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IVideoConferenceService" name="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Has anybody got any suggestions? This annoying error has taken days of my time thus far.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

When I check the files being retrieved in my web sessions using fiddler, it shows that my browser is retrieving the client access policy file, so I think the error lies somewhere else and WCF is just throwing this error at me? I've also set IE9 to clear its cache everytime its close. Take a look below.

[image]

Comment: I would check that your clientaccesspolicy is being requested and has not been cached, I've observed that these policy files can be cached aggressively. I would clear your cache and watch your requests (using network monitor in IE9 dev tools, Firebug, Fiddler, etc) to see the clientaccesspolicy being fetched by your browser.

Comment: thanks, will try that now and see what happens.

Comment: @ Rus, I did that but it didn't seem to resolve the issue. I also set my browser to always clean its cache. I updated my answer, be grateful if you could take a look.

Comment: BTW, it is interesting that you stated self-hosting is ok for the SL client to call the WCF service. Did you configure clientaccesspolicy.xml then? If you did not configure that it should not work at all.

Comment: Yea obviously I had to configure the clientaccesspolicy for the self hosted service as well. I was manually retrieving the cllientaccesspolicy. I placed a breakpoint right before opening the service host to check whether the policy was being read, and in the self hosted environment it was always being read whenever a client proxy was created. Basically I did [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2010/05/07/how-to-consume-a-self-hosted-wcf-service-in-a-cross-domain-environment-by-silverlight-client.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just managed to get it working. Couple of points worth mentioning are that:

**1.** If you look at the *erroneous* `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` that I posted above (generated by visual studio when I gave the service address as: `http://localhost/Conference/VideoConferenceService.svc` ) you can see that the netTcp port which is `4502`, was not generated as part of the endpoint, this is what what causing the TCP error 10016 (`EndpointNotFoundException`) as well as TCP error 10013. The correct `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig is` actually:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:4502/Conference/VideoConferenceService.svc"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IVideoConferenceService" name="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**2.** When I was hosting my service in IIS 7, I was giving the port range `808:*` as the netTcp ports, whereas I should have given `4502:*` as the port range, like below:

[image]

Also from what I gathered, the website hosting the service should be on port 80, as Silverlight will look in `localhost:80/ClientAccessPolicy.xml` for the client access policy file.

And just for the record, for those who stumble across this same problem, this `web.config` managed to work in IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>

   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
       <service name="VideoServer.VideoConferenceService">
         <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService" contract="VideoServer.IVideoConferenceService" />
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       </service>
     </services>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IVideoConferenceService" portSharingEnabled="false" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" listenBacklog="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" openTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" sendTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
            <transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also worth noting that you don't need to put any ports or base addresses in the `web.config` for IIS. It will create the service endpoint using the port `4502`, I tried  changing it to 4503, 4522 etc. and interestingly it didn't work with those ports, only with 4502.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem as specified in the original post. Just to help anyone who has not been able to resolve the issue with the solutions provided above, we found that the Windows firewall on the machine hosting the service was blocking the port we were trying to connect with net.tcp through. Once we allowed the traffic through the port on that software firewall our service started working as expected.

It may be worth checking any hardware firewall you might have in place as well to allow the ranges 4502-4530 I believe for net.tcp